# External monitor cannot be set to 4K resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I have an LG 4K monitor that used to work fine at 2160p connected to my MacBook. I tried connecting my android phone to the monitor to test it. Since then, whenever I plug the monitor into my MacBook, the monitor's resolution is set to 800x600.

I have tried going into 'display settings', clicking on 'scaled', and checking the 'show all resolutions' dialogue box, but it only shows resolutions up to 1920x1080. I tried restarting my laptop and reconnecting the monitor, but the issue persists. I also tried to connect my Windows laptop to the monitor, and it displays 4k just fine.

I have an M1 MacBook Pro and am using a usb-c dongle to connect the monitor via HDMI. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reboot the Mac with the screen connected & on.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a weird solution. I used a DisplayPort to USB-C cable to connect to my MacBook. The resolution was 4K by default. I then switched back to using HDMI and the resolution stayed at 4K. I am guessing that using a different connection reset the monitor settings on my MacBook.